# Автоматическое открытие окна после его закрытия JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

На данный момент при попытке закрыть вкладку браузера выбивает алёрт (вы уверены что хотите закрыть?), а надо сделать так, чтобы алёрт не выбивало, пользователь закрывал окно, и автоматически открывалось новое (тут - index.html). И будет ли это работать в браузерах под андроид? Спасибо.

```
window.onbeforeunload =  confirm;
function confirm() {
    return window.open("index.html");
}
```

Comment: 1. Не надо называть Ваши функции так же, как называются методы объекта `window`. 2. Если пользователь хочет закрыть окно, надо дать ему это сделать.

Comment: Afaik, невозможно. При закрытии окна все его содержимое, в том числе и любые работающие скрипты, уничтожается. Ну и вообще, если бы такая возможность существовала, ей бы давно пользовались всякие вирусописатели.

Comment: @Yaant - возможно. Автор, собственно, это уже делает, используя `window.onbeforeunload`.

Comment: @Igor, хм, и это реально работает в современных браузерах?

Comment: @Igor, невозможно, если пользователь нажмет в настоящем конфирме все равно уйти. в данном случае даже не будет выполнен open. В _onbeforeunload_ вообще куча ограничений что можно выполнить